# Redhat NFS Cluster High Load average suddenly

Tags: redhat, nfs

We have noticed that on a specific day in a week the load average on redhat nfs cluster goes high & i am unable to find the root cause for this.

disk read/writes are also okay on this day. Has anyone got such issue with redhat NFS cluster server?.

Answer (score 1):

Is this *actually* a problem, is response times for users degraded?

> ### [Linux Load Averages: Solving the Mystery](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-08-08/linux-load-averages.html)
>
> Linux load averages are "system load averages" that show the running thread (task) demand on the system as an average number of running plus waiting threads.
>
> If they are higher than your CPU count, then you *might* have a
>   performance problem (it depends).

To get the list of running tasks for everyone, run something like  `ps -ref` and note the PIDs containing STAT of R. Or run `top`  and look for R in the S column.

Identify processes, and determine what the resource they are limited by. Highly dependent on what exactly is in the run queue.   The approach in general is called the [Thread State Analysis (TSA) Method](http://www.brendangregg.com/tsamethod.html).

And, what does disk being "okay" mean? How many IOPS does it do, what are the read and write response time statistics, is it spindles or solid state?